# Сложная сортировка в MySQL по двум полям паралельно

Tags: mysql, сортировка

Есть таблица упрощено со следующими полями: `id, status, date`.
Нужно выбрать в начале все поля со `status = new`, а все оставшиеся поля сортировать по `date`. Если можно решение желательно через конструкцию `ORDER BY`

Comment: `ORDER BY status='new' DESC, date`

Comment: @Akina А в поле ответ почему не вписали? Надо исправить.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете перечислить поля и порядок сортировки в `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY
  status = 'new' DESC, /* отсортирует по флагу */
  date /* следом отсортирует по дате */
```